# Progamming inside a Attiny85 with rust

Tags: rust, embedded, attiny

### Introduction

I created a small project that uploads C++ code to an Attiny85, for this I used arduino.

### Question

But I would have liked to know if it was possible to download and run rust code in Attiny85 or other Attiny.
If we can, how do we do it?

### Details

I found this GitHub repo to do this, but it is not explicit on how can export the rust code to Attiny.
The GitHub repo in question: https://github.com/q231950/avr-attiny85-rust?ref=https://githubhelp.com

Comment: You used your favorite web search engine with the keywords "cross compile rust for avr", didn't you? What have you found, and why does it not answer your questions?

Comment: Thank you for your help, I did not find an article talking about the Attiny85 or another Attiny.
The only lead I found is this GitHub repo: https://github.com/q231950/avr-attiny85-rust?ref=https://githubhelp.com

Comment: You do not "export" Rust code. It is compiled, equally to  C++, into a final "_hex_" file containing the machine code. And then you use Avrdude to flash this into the microcontroller. You might need to learn a lot about development with command line tools. Unfortunately this is too broad an issue to post here.

Comment: It does not take much Google-fu to find exactly what you are looking for, but understanding the concepts of compiled languages and cross-compilation might result in a more fruitful search.  That is to say; to find what you are looking for, you have to know what you are looking for _is_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C++ is cross-compiled to AVR machine code on your development host.  What you are loading *is not* C++ code; that is the *source code* used to generate the machine executable binary code, which is what you load..

You can develop for AVR using any language for which a cross compiler exists.  Rust is certainly [such a language](https://www.avr-rust.com). [This article](https://dev.to/creativcoder/how-to-run-rust-on-arduino-uno-40c0) discusses using Rust on Arduino Uno hardware.

Whether ATTiny85 with only 8Kb of Flash and 512 bytes of SRAM will support a Rust runtime environment and any useful code I cannot tell; I am not familiar with Rust's runtime requirements, but it does not seem like an efficient use of limited resources to me, and I would treat it as an academic challenge rather than a practical development approach. I would expect Rust to have a considerably larger run-time footprint than C or even C++.

Comment: Rust's "runtime" can be negligible, for simple applications.  There's no particular reason it couldn't run on an 8K device.